# Using initialPos from Reactjs state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I am building a React component with fixed width and resizable height. The problem is I am getting `event.clientY` and `this.state.initialPos` with unpredictable values. Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rob111/79du6zfq/6/)

And here is code of React component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../styles/cal-event-styles.css';

class CalEvent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDragging: false,
      height: 40,
      text: this.props.text,
      color: this.props.color
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('mousemove', this.resizePanel);
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopResize);
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('mouseleave', this.stopResize);
  }

  resizePanel = (event) => {
    if (this.state.isDragging) {
//I tried to use event.clientY - this.state.initialPos but it doesn't work
      let delta = event.clientY + this.state.height;
      console.log("event.clentY " + event.clientY);
      console.log("this.state.initialPos " + this.state.initialPos);
      this.setState({height: delta});
    }
  }

  stopResize = () => {
    if (this.state.isDragging) {
      this.setState({
        isDragging: false,
      });
    }
    // height: this.getStep(this.state.height)
  }

  getStep = (height) => {
    return Math.floor(height / 50) * 50;
  }

  startResize = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      isDragging: true,
      initialPos: event.clientX
    });
  }

  formatText = () => {
    const { text, height } = this.state;
    return text.length > 10 && height <= 100 ? text.substring(0, 14) + "..." : text;
  }

  render(){
    const {color, text, height, isDragging, initialPos } = this.state;

    console.log("this.state.isDragging: " + isDragging);
    if (isDragging) {

      console.log("this.state.height: " + height);
      console.log("this.state.initialPos: " + initialPos);
    }
    return(
      <div className="cal-event" onMouseUp={() => this.stopResize()} style={{height: `${height}px`, background: color}}>
        <div className="cal-event-tile"><p>{this.formatText()}</p></div>
        <div className="resizer-height" onMouseDown={e => this.startResize(e)}></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CalEvent;
```

Comment: I think you messed up the delta calculation mate, delta is suppose to be the difference between starting point and current point, not a sum of initial value and current point.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this line:

```
let delta = event.clientY + this.state.height
```

delta shouldn't be the sum of those values, because you resize on the Y axis and exactly the Y (in this case) should determine the new height:

I tried this in the `resizePanel` method and it seem to work:

```
this.setState({ height: event.clientY })
```

The problem with this approach is that, in this case, the top position of the component is almost 0, and that is why it work quite seemlessly.

If you need it to work no matter where the component is placed on the page, you have to compute `delta` as the difference between the top position and the `event.clientY`.

To do it, I would save the absolute top position of the component in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const currentNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
  currentNode.addEventListener('mousemove', this.resizePanel);
  currentNode.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopResize);
  currentNode.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.stopResize);
  this.setState({ initialY: currentNode.getBoundingClientRect().top })
}
```

Then, in the event handler, the setting of the height property will be:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ height: event.clientY - prevState.initialY }))
```